# In-house video hosting options?

Tags: apache, video, video-streaming, h.264

I have an ever-growing archive of employee-submitted video-tutorials that I want to make available internally to everyone in the company to stream and watch. I want the videos to be embed-able in our company's intranet website.

The available options I can think of are:

- Share a network drive: Downside - Cannot embed in intranet webpages so that people can access through browsers. Not scalable since there is a cap on simultaneous users
- Youtube: Downside: There is a lot of sensitive information we don't out to put out in the open
- Paid cloud hosting, e.g. Brightcove: Our video archive is quite huge and growing every day since it is user-submitted content - so cost is an issue. We don't want to do the cloud since we have available server-space.
- video hosting softwares: Did not find much info on this

Are there other options worth considering?
My question is not directly related to programming - but posted it here anyway expecting answers with a programmatic approach (e.g. Apache plugin etc.)

Comment: I've found a quite a few media streaming servers [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_streaming_media_systems). Some are open source. Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101573/opensource-streaming-server-application). This [link](http://flowplayer.org/tutorials/introduction-to-streaming-servers.html) seems to discuss about your options.